# How do I write a multi-frequency audio file?

Tags: python, linux, audio, wav

I am trying to write an audio file with tones from 440hz to 600hz. The file should start at 440hz and then play each frequency (in increasing order) for 1 second, ending at 600hz. I've come up with python's wave module, but am doing something wrong here, as I end up with a file with no sound. (If someone has a better suggestion, I really don't care if it's in python or not. I am using Linux and anything that will work on that platform will do fine. I just need to create an audio file with the above specs. thx!)

```
frequencies = range(440,600)
data_size = len(frequencies)
fname = "WaveTest.wav"
frate = 11025.0  # framerate as a float
amp = 64000.0     # multiplier for amplitude

sine_list_x = []
for f in frequencies:
    for x in range(data_size):
        sine_list_x.append(math.sin(2*math.pi*f*(x/frate)))

wav_file = wave.open(fname, "w")

nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = int(frate)
nframes = data_size
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"

wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes,
    comptype, compname))

for s in sine_list_x:
    # write the audio frames to file
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(s*amp/2)))

wav_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: hopefully its at least a good starting point for you to continue.

```
import numpy as N
import wave

towrite = ''
for freq in xrange(440,600):
     duration = 1
     samplerate = 44100
     samples = duration*samplerate
     period = samplerate / float(freq) # in sample points
     omega = N.pi * 2 / period

     xaxis = N.arange(samples,dtype = N.float)
     ydata = 16384 * N.sin(xaxis*omega)

     signal = N.resize(ydata, (samples,))

     towrite += ''.join([wave.struct.pack('h',s) for s in signal])

 f = wave.open('freqs.wav', 'wb')
 f.setparams((1,2,44100, 44100*4, 'NONE', 'noncompressed'))
 f.writeframes(towrite)
 f.close()
```

[Reference](http://codingmess.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-make-simple-wav-file-with-python.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to works fine for me on a Windows plateform :

[image: start of the signal at 440 Hz]

[image: end of the signal at 600 Hz]

The sampling is respected and the frequencies are just right (from 440 to 600 Hz). 
However, in your code the frequencies does not stay for one second, but for len(frequencies)/frate-th of second. If you want to have a full second for every frequency, data_size should be equal to frate.

```
import math
import wave
import struct

frequencies = range(440,600)
duration = 1 #in second
fname = "WaveTest.wav"
frate = 11025.0  # framerate as a float
amp = 64000.0     # multiplier for amplitude

sine_list_x = []
for f in frequencies:
    for x in range(duration*frate)  :
        sine_list_x.append(math.sin(2*math.pi*f*(x/frate)))

wav_file = wave.open(fname, "w")

nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = int(frate)
nframes = data_size
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"

wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes,
    comptype, compname))

for s in sine_list_x:
    # write the audio frames to file
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(s*amp/2)))

wav_file.close()
```